# Sargable query versus function, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've always thought that a query that uses `LIKE 'Z%'` in a `WHERE` clause is sargable, whereas a query that uses `LEFT (ColA, 1) = 'Z'` is not.

So I ran a little test.

```
CREATE TABLE #Person (ID INT IDENTITY, LastName VARCHAR (50))
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX i_PersonID ON #Person (ID)
GO

INSERT INTO #Person 
VALUES ('Peters'), ('Michaels'), ('Richarson'), ('Stevens'),
       ('Wade'), ('Zachery')
GO 10000
```

Query 1: 8 seconds

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Person 
WHERE LEFT (Lastname, 1) = 'Z'
GO 100
```

Query 2: 8 seconds

```
SELECT *  
FROM #Person 
WHERE LastName LIKE 'Z%'
GO 100
```

There is no difference in performance here. Is there something wrong with my test of was my understanding of sargability wrong in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sargability has to do with the ability of the database to use an index on a column.  But in your example, the `LastName` column has no index, so this is really a moot point.  Also, you test data set is very small, and, even if `LastName` did have an index, SQL Server might very well decide not to use that index anyway.

If you use a larger dataset, add an index on `LastName`, and add some data where the index would help the query, I expect you would see a difference.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I will run some new tests and add an index on the name column.

Comment: Adjusted table size to 600k rows and added an non-clustered index. First query ran 20 seconds, second one ran 5 secs. Also, major difference in logical reads. Thanks!